# collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status in eclipse cdt

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm a beginner of programming. I am using Eclipse CDT for C programming. When I  build any program, the console window shows the below message. Please tell me a  specific way so that I could solve this problem.

Console window:

```
Info: Configuration "Debug" uses tool-chain "MinGW GCC" that is unsupported on this system, attempting to build anyway.
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o test.o "..\\test.c" 
gcc -o test.exe test.o 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../i686-pc-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file test.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

00:33:35 Build Finished (took 2s.385ms)
```

Comment: try turn off any anti-virus if you have running in your system. try to run Eclipse as Administrator...

Comment: Thanks for helping me...

Comment: I can't believe if it worked. Did it ? :)

Answer (score 0):

USUALLY(in my experience), LD errors result from you not including the libraries or linkers necessary. Go to your project, right click, select properties, under C build go to settings, GCC C compiler and includes and add the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Your operating system simply does not allow to modify a file while it is in use, so the compilation  fails, because compiler can't remove the old executable and place a new one. To solve this, simply restart  eclipse program.